# Auto-calculate width for standard WinAPI controls

Tags: winapi, checkbox, radio-button, controls

I am trying to write a general-purpose function to automatically calculate the width of several standard types of WinAPI controls based on the current caption/text content. This code works very well for getting the width of the text:

```cpp
HWND hWnd = GetDlgItem(GetWindowHandle(), GetControlID());
int textLen = GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd);
std::wstring ctrlText(textLen, 0);
GetWindowTextW(hWnd, ctrlText.data(), static_cast<int>(ctrlText.size()));
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HFONT hFont = (HFONT)SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
if (!hFont)
    hFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT);
HFONT hOldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
SIZE textSize{};
GetTextExtentPoint32W(hdc, ctrlText.data(), static_cast<int>(ctrlText.size()), &textSize);
```

Although the documentation says the result in `textSize.cx` is "logical units", the result appears to be window horizontal pixels. If I assume that scale I am able derive what appears to be the correct number of pixels in my dpi-aware app.

The question comes with what to do about the `WC_BUTTON` controls that I use for radio buttons and checkboxes. Is there any proper way to calculate the additional width of the radio button or checkbox? Currently I am hard-coding an additional value per control type. But that seems like a poor choice, notwithstanding that ChatGPT recommended hard-coding it as well. I am looking for a better solution.

EDIT: Based on the code above (which now includes assigning the font), I added the following code to try to use themes as suggested:

```cpp
HTHEME hTheme = OpenThemeData(hWnd, L"BUTTON");
if (hTheme)
{
    RECT rcContent{}, rcBounds{};
    HRESULT rslt = GetThemeBackgroundContentRect(hTheme, hdc, partID, contentID, &rcBounds, &rcContent);
    if (rslt != S_OK)
    {
        LONG errCode = GetLastError();
    }
    MARGINS margins{};
    rslt = GetThemeMargins(hTheme, hdc, partID, contentID, TMT_CONTENTMARGINS, NULL, &margins);
    if (rslt != S_OK)
    {
        LONG errCode = GetLastError();
    }
    CloseThemeData(hTheme);
    LONG width = (rcBounds.right - rcBounds.left) + margins.cxLeftWidth + margins.cxRightWidth;
}
SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc); // release hdc moved here (compared to above)
```

I have verified in the debugger that no error is occurring. (That is, the `!= S_OK` paths are not being taken.) But the rectangles (and margins) returned are all zeros. Does anyone see where I have gone astray?

Comment: Maybe GetThemeBackgroundContentRect and GetThemeMargins? (I am blind now and so can't see this sort of thing anymore so I am submitting this as a comment rather than answer).

Comment: The DC you get from `GetDC` has a default font in it; you'll want to set it to the actual font the control is using if you want your calculation to be accurate.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I added setting the font, but weirdly it produced a scaled value that was well off from what it should be. I'm wondering if instead of assuming dpi of 96 I should use the actual dpi of the window.

Comment: EDIT: nevermind I figured it out.

Comment: It appears that, despite the documentation, GetTextExtentPoint32W returns window pixels and not logical units. This may be because the control's font is scaled to the DPI resolution of the monitor and the result is the same. If someone has a better explanation, I would be interested to know it.

Comment: are you using a CS_OWNDC window? That changes a lot of logical units vs screen pixel returns.

Comment: My code does not create the parent window, so I am not 100% certain, but it is not set in the result from `GetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_STYLE)`, so I'm going to say no. It is not set on the control either.

Comment: Also, fwiw, `GetThemePartSize` returns a size (26x26) but the part drawing destination rect is also all zeros.

Comment: Microsoft have never documented an official way to calculate this afaik. In our own code we use `GetThemePartSize` if themes are active, otherwise load the system bitmap `OBM_CHECKBOXES` and calculate from its size (width / 4, height / 3).

Comment: If you want to (are able to) show some sample code in an answer, I would be most grateful and check it. In particular, there seems still to be a fudge factor for the gap between the checkbox and the start of text.

Comment: You can use the application [theme-explorer](https://github.com/mity/theme-explorer) to check these theme settings. [It seems to be TS_TRUE or TS_DRAW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruFDf.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetThemePartSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-getthemepartsize) can retrieve the size data referring to [Parts and States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/parts-and-states), which also is pointed out by @JonathanPotter.

```
HTHEME hTheme = OpenThemeData(NULL, L"BUTTON");
if (hTheme)
{
    SIZE size{};
    HRESULT hr = GetThemePartSize(hTheme,NULL, BP_RADIOBUTTON, RBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL,NULL, TS_DRAW,&size);//13*13
    hr = GetThemePartSize(hTheme,NULL, BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL,NULL, TS_DRAW,&size);//13*13
}
```

Comment: This works for me, but it isn't the whole story for some reason. There are some other parts that add to the width that I haven't been able to determine. (Interestingly, the SIZE I get back is 26x26 because my window is running at 192dpi.) Also, I can't get the combox buttons to return anything like the right values. They seem to be returning 96dpi values rather than scaled values like the buttons.

Comment: But I'm going to check this answer because I did end up using it for buttons with a hard-coded fudge factor tacked on.